# Does Visual Studio2022 have <> in the name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-6.0

I saw a library code variable named like this

```
  private readonly Encoder <Encoder>k__BackingField;
```

I tried to name it in Visual Studio 2022 but it didn't work

Can c# name add angle brackets? Which version of grammar is it?

Comment: `private readonly Encoder<Encoder> k__BackingField` you maybe mistyped a space.. Look for more information about [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)

Comment: Was that actual writtensource code you looked at? Because that looks like a compiler generated backing field that you mostly see after decompiling an assembly.

Comment: "Decompiled" IL can look a little strange when converted to C# as there are all sorts of things that are valid IL but invalid C#.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I bet that it is not about generics but about compiler generated field names which OP sees with some kind of decompilation tool.

Answer (score -1):

The angle brackets (< and >) are used for generic type parameters, and they are not allowed in variable names.

Examples that work are:

```
private readonly Encoder<T> tEncoder;

private readonly Encoder<string> stringEncoder;
```

...

Comment: Not in C#, but they *are* allowed in IL, which is why the C# compiler uses them when it needs to synthesize fields, e.g. based on local variables. I think that's much more likely than that this was a deliberate attempt to use generics, especially given the rest of the name.